# Host nodejs app and Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, node.js, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

I need to host 2 solutions. The first is a nodejs app which should be consumed using sockets from various client apps (mobile, website...). Then, a Wordpress website. Both must have the same database because data has to be shared between the website and the nodejs application.

So, which cloud provider can be the best to host these two projects ? Something like AWS or Azure (Websites, cloudservice, VM, ... ?), or OVH or Ikoula which are really less expansive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know AWS will work. I haven't really dealt with the others yet. I use AWS for quite a few projects and so far I've had no issues.